# Can't Delete WebLogic Server Instance

Tags: java, configuration, weblogic, weblogic11g

I'm trying to get a clustered WebLogic instance up and going on the server.  New to this I'm finding some of the actions of it confusing.  I actually cloned another instance of another server to see if I can at least get the base server and up and going, however, this didn't work. When I went to delete the server instance on WebLogic it tells me "The server WLS_MY_SERVER_INSTANCE is a running server and may not be deleted."  This is rather confusing because when I look at running  state of the server it says FAILED_NOT_RESTARTABLE.  How can I remove this server instance?  This is WebLogic 11g.  This Server is not local but actually on a server and I'm working w/the WebLogic console in order to configure the instance of this WLS_MY_SERVER_INSTANCE server.  I have a feeling this has something to do with me cloning another instance because previously I was able to delete the server.  I'm new to this configuring of the server so any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to this is to remove the instance from the machine and simply delete the IP from the configuration.  Once this is done and saved the system changes the status to SHUTDOWN and then allows you to DELETE the instance.